Are Stokes parameters Lorentz invariant?
Are the Stokes parameters for polarization relativistic? i.e. Lorentz invariant? And if it is so, then how to show it?

For simplicity, let's consider a plane monochromatic wave propagating in $\hat z$ direction. If we parametrize the Stokes parameters in terms of the propagating electric field (see Born and Wolf, Principles of Optics ch. 1 section 1.4.2):
$$
\begin{aligned}
S_0 &= E_x^2+E_y^2\\
S_1 &= E_x^2-E_y^2\\
S_2 &= 2E_xE_y\cos(\phi_x-\phi_y)\\
S_3 &= 2E_yE_y\sin(\phi_x-\phi_y)
\end{aligned}
$$
Now, the fields are components of a second order tensor. In general, the electric field transform like (see D. Jackson, Classical Electrodynamics Ch. 11.10)
$$
\vec E' = \gamma (\vec E + \vec \beta \times \vec B) - {\gamma^2\over \gamma+1}\vec \beta (\vec \beta \cdot \vec E)
$$
So for example, a boost in $x$ direction will not affect $E_x$, but will affect $E_y$ and $E_z$ and so on. For all directions, at least two components would change. We can verify if perpendicular boost produce effects that cancel each other in $x$ and $y$ directions, recovering invariance of the Stokes parameters. A boost in $z$ direction will affect both $E_x$ and $E_y$, in such a way that
$$
\begin{aligned}
E_z'&=E_z=0\\
E_x'&=\gamma (E_x-\beta B_y)\\
E_y'&=\gamma (E_y+\beta B_x)
\end{aligned}
$$
But is easy to see that the Stokes parameters will change. For example
$$
\begin{aligned}
S_0'&= \gamma^2 S_0 - 2\gamma\beta \vec E\times \vec B +\gamma^2\beta^2B^2
\end{aligned}
$$
So Stoked parameters are not Lorentz invariant.

For a good answer like this one to a question that needs help (in this case, clarifying the title), I would also suggest editing the question after answering. There's a badge in it, I believe. (Either way, +1 from me.)
